# How to Duplicate a Linearlayout with all views inside it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout and it contains some Views.
How can I duplicate it programmatically?

my Layouts are as below:

```
linearLayout1 (vertical)
  linearLayout2 (horizontal)
    textView1
    textView2
    imageView
    imageView
```

I want to duplicate linearLayout2 (horizontal)

Comment: Do you want to duplicate this within the same activity or across multiple activities?

Comment: Why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: @PedroVarela There are many reasons for reusing a layout. `ListView` is one of many examples. It duplicates the same layout for each row.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Please see my edit which adds another choice which is probably much more appropriate for you.

Comment: I want to know more about Mohammad's question so I can provide a possible solution, buy this duplication makes me think immediately on RecyclerView, so the layout can be "duplicated"

Comment: @PedroVarela That's a good point. My earlier comment made me think of `ListView` which I hadn't considered originally for my own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions to your problem:

1. Use a `ListView` instead of `linearLayout1`.
2. Use a `RecyclerView` instead of `linearLayout1`.
3. Use a `Fragment`.
4. Create a custom `View` subclass.

All of these options have many online tutorials. I suggest you do some research. If you get stuck on something, please come back with more questions. Most likely a `ListView` will be the most appropriate option for you. Even with a `ListView`, you might consider creating a custom `View` subclass for each row. However, to begin, this is not entirely necessary. I'm just saying that these two choices are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Give the LinearLayout an ID. Use `findViewById` to find that View.

You can now add that View again to any other `ViewGroup` (such as a `LinearLayout`) with `addView()`

Comment: While this is a workable solution, I think `ListView` or `RecyclerView` would be better since it does a lot of the work for you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Probably - should've asked for more clarification from the question

Answer (score 0):

In the device view in android studio click on the layout and just copy paste

Comment: While this works, it also duplicates the effort of making changes and fixing bugs.